# After VS2017 Update 3: "No agent could be found with the following capabilities"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After I upgraded my build machines to VS2017 Update 3 (aka 15.3.1), I get the following error message:
    "No agent could be found with the following capabilities: DotNetFramework, msbuild, visualstudio, vstest"

What I have tried so far:

- Restart the service (as the agent runs as a service)
- Reboot the VM
- Remove/Reconfigure the agent
- Review the log files in _diag (but did not find errors or related lines)
- Manually ran /bin/powershell/Add-Capabitilies.ps1 for error messages or clues 
  but nothing helped :-(

Thank you for any help you may provide!

Jean

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TFS do you use? TFS 2017 Update1 or Update2?

Please try below things to narrow down the issue:

1. Check if the capabilities are installed on the Agent machine. If
   they are installed, try to manually add them as **USER
   CAPABILITIES**, reference below screenshot.

   eg:

   `DotNetFramework   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`

   `MSBuild   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\`

   `VSTest   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow`
2. Uninstall VS 2017 and the Agent >>  Re-deploy the agent  >> 
   Reinstall VS 2017, Start the agent service, then try it again.

   The system capabilities are only discovered when the agent is first configured -- any changes made after that are not captured.
3. Prepare a new agent machine, deploy the agent and install VS 2017.
4. If your TFS is not TFS 2017 Update2, try upgrading to Update 2
   version, as an related issue fixed in update2, see
   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85660/tfs-build-agent-on-premise-fails-to-build-msbuild.html

[image]

Comment: @jeanga Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? Any update?

Comment: Hi, 
I was still using Update 1.
Upgraded to 2, remove/reconfigure the agent did not solve the issue.
Currently in progress of VS2017U3 uninstall/reinstall.
Will report back after this.
Thanks for the follow up.
Jean

Comment: BTW, I do not understand how "user" capabilities work.
As soon as I tried to insert "user" capabilities, all "system" capabilities vanished. Panicked, I removed the "User" ones and the system ones came back...
As a side note, I do not understand how this trick could be a valid workaround...

Comment: Uninstall/Install + agent re-deploy did not solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Andy, 
You have also to know that the VS2017U3 upgrade (from U2) was performed using an offline layout (i.e. not the online setup), on a disconnected network.
I had to manually confirm the execution of a couple of binaries (for Windows SDK if I remember correctly).
I followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-in-offline-environment for the initial setup.

Comment: Manually adding the capabilities seems to solve the issue so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot mark it as an answer because my reputation does not allow me to do it... If I ever become reputable enough, I promise to get back here and mark this answer correctly.